# How to write scodec codec for Collection Map

Tags: scala, scodec

I have below case class

```
case class Foo(code: Int, msg: String, headers: Map[String,String] = Map.empty)
```

Below is the code that I've tried so far -

```
import scodec._
import scodec.codecs._

implicit val mapCodec: Codec[List[(String, String)]] = sizedList()

implicit val fooCodec : Codec[Foo] = {
    ("code" | int32) :: ("msg" | cstring) :: ("headers" | mapCodec)
}.as[Foo]
```

I don't know how to write Codec for `Map[String, String]`. I checked online documentation but it is still in TODO.

Any idea how can I write the codec for `Map[String, String]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would need to do is to define `Codec` for tuple of strings, which then you will need to use to create codec for `List[(String, String)]` which can be converted to `Map[String, String]` and vice versa, hence covert `Codec` using `xmap` function.

So the final solution might look like:

```scala
import scodec._
import scodec.codecs._
case class Foo(code: Int, msg: String, headers: Map[String,String] = Map.empty)

implicit val tupleCodec : Codec[(String, String)] = cstring.pairedWith(cstring)
implicit val mapCodec: Codec[Map[String, String]] = list(tupleCodec).xmap(_.toMap, _.toList)

implicit val fooCodec : Codec[Foo] = {
  ("code" | int32) :: ("msg" | cstring) :: ("headers" | mapCodec)
}.as[Foo]
```

Hope this helps!